# InDesign inline column reflow?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

In InDesign, I know that I can break a text box into columns pretty easily by selecting it and playing with these options:

[image: Text box column options]

I also know that I can set up the margins and columns and then use linked text boxes to do columns:

[image: Linked text box columns]

However, neither of these do what I want to do, and I haven't really found a really elegant solution, so I thought I'd ask here.

I have one-column text box, but I want to do some columns, like this:

[image: What I want to do]

This is easy to do in Word - you select the text you want to reflow, go to `Page Layout` > `Columns`, pick a number, and you're more or less set. But is there a way to do the same thing in InDesign? I've done things like tabbing and separate text boxes, but these are not very elegant solutions.

Comment: I discovered the answer as I was typing this question, but instead of discarding the question entirely I figured I'll post up the answer in case anyone else runs into this. This is going change my world just a little bit :D

Answer (score 7):

Inline columns are done with Paragraph Styles. Create a style, double-click to edit the style, and look for the `Span Columns` option on the left:

[image: "Span Columns" screenshot]